# Gif is not working for the first time using glide

Tags: java, android, gif, android-glide

I am making an app that has a list of two items that have two gifs, one in each (the same gif). As you can see in the video, when you click on the gif, the gif is not shown in motion and it is shown as a solid image, but when you click the right or left arrow it is shown correctly in motion despite that the function to load the gif is called in both the OnCreate function and the btn_next.setOnClickListener() function and the btn_prev.setOnClickListener() function. So the same thing is done but onCreate() the gif is not shown in motion and on btn_next and btn_prev setOnClickListener() it is shown. Please, someone could tell me what could be happening here? Bcause actually the same code is executed but on the first clikc is not working
Video: https://youtube.com/shorts/S5fDsqu3CeI?feature=share

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dialog);
        
        
        init();
        glide();
    }

    private void init() {

        img_1 = findViewById(R.id.img_image1);
        btn_prev = findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_prev);
        btn_next = findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn_next);
       
        btn_next.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            glide();
        });
        btn_prev.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            glide();
            }
        });
    }

    public void glide() {
       
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.earth).into(img_1);



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code when you are initialising Glide with this.

```
Glide.with(this).asGif().load(R.raw. earth).into(img_1);
```

Comment: Is that for an olver version? This is what is shown: Cannot resolve symbol 'GlideDrawableImageViewTarget'.  Note: I AM USING THIS ->  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'

Comment: use this    Glide.with(this).asGif().load(R.raw.image_gif).into(img_1);

Comment: So I have changed this and it is doing exactly the same, it is not solving the problem -> public void glide() {
       
Glide.with(this).asGif().load(R.drawable.earth).into(img_1);



    }

Comment: as I can see in the video that there are two image views. Where is the second image view initialized?

Comment: so they are initialized like this: public class ActivityD extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView  img_exercise, btn_prev, btn_next; // this is the very first code

Comment: add code for both the activity where click listener is there and the second activity

Comment: So in the list of itmes I have this code when clicked on an item ->  public void onRecItemClick( int refId, ImageView imageView) {


        ActivityOptionsCompat activityOptionsCompat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, imageView, "imageMain");
        Intent in = new Intent(this, ActivityD.class);
        startActivity(in, activityOptionsCompat.toBundle());

    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
 Glide.with(this)
                .asGif()
                .load(R.raw._img)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(new ImageViewTarget<GifDrawable>(img) {
                    @Override
                    protected void setResource(@Nullable GifDrawable resource) {
                        img.setImageDrawable(resource);
                    }
                });
```

Add dependencies build.gradle(App Level)

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
```

Comment: Hi, so this is what I have done ->  public void glide() {
       
       Glide.with(this)
                .asGif()
                .load(R.drawable.exercise1)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(new ImageViewTarget<GifDrawable>(img_1) {
                    @Override
                    protected void setResource(@Nullable GifDrawable resource) {
                        img_1.setImageDrawable(resource);
                    }
                });



    } and it is also doing the same (see the video of what is doing) video: https://youtu.be/kvq7Fz8Vvg8

Comment: So as you see there is a new gif image (I added it to see the problem better) Basically I have made a function called glide2() same to the glide() of above and changed the dawable in .load only.